# How should I pass 2 parameters to csv-writer from my list?

Tags: python, list, csv, export

Currently I'm trying to save my list `bitrateListEqualized` of format:

```
[[2.221408], ['Wed Oct  2 11:05:28 2019']]
[[2.347744], ['Wed Oct  2 11:05:29 2019']]
[[2.47408], ['Wed Oct  2 11:05:30 2019']]
```

to `.csv` file using such code:

```
with open("/home/user/bitrateFolder/Bitrate_history_ip_{}:{}.csv".format(MCAST_GRP,MCAST_PORT,),"w+", newline='') as csvfile:
        thewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        thewriter.writerow(['values','dates'])
        for x in range(len(bitrateListEqualized)):
            bitrateListEqualized[x][0][0] = bitrateListEqualized[x][0][0]*8/(SAMPLING_TIME*1000000)
            data = [bitrateListEqualized[x]]
            thewriter.writerow(data)
        thewriter.writerow(max(bitrateListEqualized))
        thewriter.writerow(min(bitrateListEqualized))
```

the result of saving such list is:

```
values,dates
"[[10.73856], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:23 2019']]"
"[[10.780672], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:24 2019']]"
"[[10.73856], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:25 2019']]"
"[[10.73856], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:26 2019']]"
"[[10.759616000000001], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:27 2019']]"
"[[10.73856], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:28 2019']]"
"[[10.770143999999998], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:29 2019']]"
"[[10.73856], ['Wed Oct  2 11:11:30 2019']]"
[10.780672],['Wed Oct  2 11:11:24 2019']
[10.73856],['Wed Oct  2 11:11:23 2019']
```

I would like to have `.csv` file looking like this:

```
values,dates
10.73856,Wed Oct  2 11:11:23 2019
10.780672,Wed Oct  2 11:11:24 2019
10.73856,Wed Oct  2 11:11:25 2019
10.780672,Wed Oct  2 11:11:24 2019
10.73856,Wed Oct  2 11:11:23 2019
```

Could you help me guys? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turn you list into a flat list before the csv creating iteration

```
bitrateListEqualized  = [
    [[2.221408], ['Wed Oct  2 11:05:28 2019']],
    [[2.347744], ['Wed Oct  2 11:05:29 2019']],
    [[2.47408], ['Wed Oct  2 11:05:30 2019']]
]



flat_lst = [[x[0][0],x[1][0]]for x in bitrateListEqualized]
print(flat_lst)
```

output

```
[[2.221408, 'Wed Oct  2 11:05:28 2019'], [2.347744, 'Wed Oct  2 11:05:29 2019'], [2.47408, 'Wed Oct  2 11:05:30 2019']]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues to solve: writing to csv with a list of list of lists, and sorting this at the end.

Here's what I came up with:

```
with open("/home/user/bitrateFolder/{}_{}.csv".format(MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT), "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        thewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        thewriter.writerow(['values','dates'])
        for e in bitrateListEqualized:
            thewriter.writerow([e[0][0]*8/(SAMPLING_TIME*1000000), e[1][0]])
        sorted_bilateralListEqualizer = sorted([[e[0][0], e[1][0]] for e in bitrateListEqualized], key=itemgetter(1))
        thewriter.writerow(sorted_bilateralListEqualizer[-1]) # max
        thewriter.writerow(sorted_bilateralListEqualizer[0]) # min
```

- I replaced your ':' with an underscore because I had problems writing the filepath.
  I iterate over your list, and for each element in your `bilateralListEqualizer`, I get the `element[0][0]`, the value, and `element[1][0]`, the date.
  These two go into a list: `[value, date]`, and then *this* can be written as a row to your csv output.
- For your min max, I extrapolated from your expected output, and used an extra step: I sorted your original list by the value (with `itemgetter`), and wrote the last (max value) and first (min value) element to the csv.

This is what the output of the sorting looks like:

`[[2.221408, 'Wed Oct  2 11:05:28 2019'], [2.347744, 'Wed Oct  2 11:05:29 2019'], [2.47408, 'Wed Oct  2 11:05:30 2019']]`

If you need more details, let me know.

This is the output I get (ignore the values' value, I created a dummy `SAMPLING_TIME`):

[image: output]